# I got a issue for InflateParams in the android

Tags: java, android

The issue is this "Avoid passing null as the view root (need to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element) "

I have made a Name list using the String[]-array to do it, not the "ArrayList<>" and I want to get the position from the array.

For this Name lists, it works used the ArrayList<>, but when I use the String[]-array and it doesn't work.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_activity_Main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_itemView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text="Name"/>
```

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayoutActivity_Main=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_activity_Main);

    String[] arrayNames= new String[]{"John", "James", "Robert", "Michael","William","David","Charles","Daniel","Mary","Joanne"};

    inflateLinearLayout(linearLayoutActivity_Main,arrayNames);
}


private void inflateLinearLayout(LinearLayout linearLayout, String[] name){

    for (int i=0; i < name.length; i++){

        View itemView =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
        TextView textView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_itemView);

        textView.setText(name[i]);

        itemView.getTag(i);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"You are on " +view.getTag()+" position",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        linearLayout.addView(itemView);

    }
}
```

When I ran the App and click the name list of the position, then it shows a message, "You are on ## position".
So, if it works, then will say yours on which position. Then right now the problem is the message shows "Your on null position".

Comment: What are you expecting `itemView.getTag(i)` to do? Did you want to set the tag instead?

Comment: Yes，set the tag to get the position from String【i】because it can't get the name【i】in the Toast message. Also，I'm not familiar with the String array，does there have any issue for the String-array？Or can I add“ view.name【i】” in the Toast message to get the position？

Comment: But you never did **set** the tag. String arrays or ArrayLists should all work the same.